# distcp2 in CDH5.2 with MR1

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-cdh, distcp

We have requirement to restrict mappers bandwidth when distcp from s3 to local cluster.

So I downloaded hadoop-distcp-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0-20141009.063640-188.jar  from https://repository.cloudera.com

Here is the link : https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/public/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-distcp/2.5.0-cdh5.2.0-SNAPSHOT/hadoop-distcp-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0-20141009.063640-188.jar

then ran following distcp command but got some error. Don't know if I am doing anything wrong g

```
export HADOOP_USER_CLASSPATH_FIRST=true && HADOOP_CLASSPATH=hadoop-distcp-2.5.0-cdh5.2.0-20141009.063640-188.jar hadoop org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp -bandwidth 1 s3n://com.xyz/2014/10/23/ hdfs:///user/abc/2014-10-23/

14/11/05 09:54:55 INFO tools.DistCp: Input Options: DistCpOptions{atomicCommit=false,    syncFolder=false, deleteMissing=false, ignoreFailures=false, maxMaps=20, sslConfigurationFile='null', copyStrategy='uniformsize', sourceFileListing=null, sourcePaths=[s3n://com.xyz.rtb/2014/10/23], targetPath=hdfs:/user/abc/2014-10-23, targetPathExists=true, preserveRawXattrs=false}
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmissionFiles.getStagingDir(Lorg/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Cluster;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/fs/Path;
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.createMetaFolderPath(DistCp.java:379)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.execute(DistCp.java:155)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.run(DistCp.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp.main(DistCp.java:401)
```

Any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://groups.google.com/a/cloudera.org/forum/#!topic/cdh-user/Ld60TY_Z-Jg

The DistCp2 is the default and only DistCp in MR2. It isn't called DistCp2, but just DistCp.

The command 'hadoop distcp' in MR2 runs DistCp2.